# How to do an action when a user click Elementor update button?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am loading Elementor post inside iframe
I want to close this iframe when the user click update in Elementor

I am look for any Elementor JS hook that i can hook when the user click update button

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this hook

`add_action( 'elementor/editor/after_save', 'log_saved_elementor_data' );`

Elementor has a hook that lets developers run code after the user has saved data in the editor.

Find more [here](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/save-editor-data/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
I saw this hook before , this is a PHP hook
I am looking for JS hook

Comment: If you want to do some action on the update button then this is the hook, You can always do JS stuff with this PHP hook anyways. Hope this helps.